# 'Sheep shift' the mocker's beds?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In S03E10, Sansa mentions that they could 'sheep shift' the beds of people who mock them.
Tyrion asks, 'But why sheep *shift*?', and Sansa explains it's the vulgar word for dung.

Is this a cute misunderstanding by Sansa (highlighting her innocence/naïveté) and does this happen in the books?

[image] [image]
[image] [image]

Comment: How do you know it's a misunderstanding? Maybe that's really the vulgar term up in The North?

Comment: @LordSnow - A shift is a folded or layered garment. It's certainly possible that this is why she persists in her belief that the word is shift rather than sh*t.

Answer (score 5):

The scene doesn't appear in the books. In the TV series, the intention seems to be to show that despite the appalling indignities to which she's been subject, that she's still young and naïve, believing the lies that her parents told her about the word "shift".

There’s a look of sad bemusement on Tyrion’s face, as if he’s once again reminded that he’s married a little girl and a look that passes between him and the (more worldly) Shae.

It's also a shared intimacy between them. Their marriage may not be born in happy circumstances but they could be happy together.